# Is there a way to simulate a paired Bluetooth device on Windows?

Tags: windows, drivers, bluetooth, emulation, simulation

Is it possible, on Windows, to simulate a connected Bluetooth device? In other words, some computer program like an emulator would show up in the Windows Bluetooth settings as an actual paired device? (A specific use case would be to make a gamepad emulator appear to the OS as if it were a real physical game controller connected via Bluetooth).